# Cyclic group of order $4$ and Klein four-group are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Klein 4-group vs. the integers modulo 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88444/the-klein-4-group-vs-the-integers-modulo-4)

> Prove that the cyclic group of order $4$ and the Klein four-group are not isomorphic.

Can someone explain what Klein four-group is and how to do this question?

Comment: In what context did you encounter the problem?  Do you have a book or notes?  Was the definition not given?  When you want to look something up quickly and don't have a reference book/notes handy, it often helps to Google key words, such as `Klein four group`, which will lead you quickly to a reference such as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Answer (score 2):

The Klein four group is $$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2,$$ where $\Bbb Z_2$ is the cyclic group of $2$ elements. In this group, every element has order at most $2$, while in a cyclic group of order $4$, two elements have order $4$, hence they cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Klein four group is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, and every elements satisfy the equation
$2x=0$,
but for $\mathbb{Z}_4$, 
it's not true. ($1+1 \neq 0$)
so they can't be isomorphic.